# Angular 4 ng-bootstrap close Modal from child component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using [ng-bootstrap' modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) and got stuck with a problem.
Situation:- I have a form component that I am showing in a modal.
Now, I want to close the modal once the user submits the form and backend confirms the success.
problem:- As guided  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938124/6500118), I don't have a reference of the modal in child component to close it.
please suggest a way.
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095010/angular-4-close-modal-after-form-submit-event-is-finished) SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the modal reference to it using a child input property.

```
<child-component [parentRef]="ref">
```

And then in your child component you'll have to define something like:

```
@Input() ref;
```

Please take a look at the Angular documentation [here.](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)